# Why are the contents in my file being replaced?

Tags: python, file, file-handling

I am a beginner in Python. I have opened a file and trying to replace the old data with it using a **TextReader** class.

I have tried debugging the code many times on PyCharm but I could not understand what is happening.

This is the TextReader class.

```
class TextReader:
    def __init__(self, spec):
       self.file = open(spec, 'r+')
       self.text = self.file.read()
       self.lines = 0
       for _ in self.file:
           self.lines += 1

    def replace(self, old, new):
        replace = ''
        for line in self.file:
            replace += line.replace(old, new) + '\n'
        self.file.write(replace)

t = TextReader('temp.txt')
t.replace('good', 'bad')
print(t.text)
print(t.lines)
```

And before running the program, the temp.txt contains:-

```
Python is a good programming language.
```

This is the output of the following code:-

```
0
```

I open the temp.txt file after running the program to see that it is empty.
Please help!

Comment: try changing the name of the variable `replace` in the `replace` method to something else as well

Comment: No effect on the output. My problem remains.

Comment: You read the entire file in the `read()` call; attempting to iterate over the still-open file handle or otherwise read again from it will simply return nothing (until you rewind the file explicitly, or by closing and text` - split that on newlines anl loop over reopening it). But you already have the data in `self.text` - split that on newlines and iterate over the lines you have in memory instead.

Comment: I have tried doing that. But I still have that problem. The file content is cleared in the __init__ method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file` objects have an internal file "offset" that gets changed whenever you read/write/seek in the file.  you're therefore implicitly reading to the end multiple times, and never `seek`ing back anywhere, e.g.:

1. your `file.read()` will be reading until the end of the file
2. you do `for _ in self.file` and `for line in self.file` these iterate over every line

all of these will leave the offset at the end.  if you don't `seek` back to the beginning again, you'll get nothing back as all these operations start at the "current offset"

I'd suggest doing as @tripleee suggests and read once, then split it into lines and then work with that, rather than repeatedly trying to rereading the same data from the different parts of the file

Answer (score 1):

Files are iterators in Python so you can only read through the file handle once. You care trying to read the same handle three times here, so the last two do nothing:

```
class TextReader:
    def __init__(self, spec):
       self.file = open(spec, 'r+') 
       self.text = self.file.read() # < reads the iterator -- it is now spent
       self.lines = 0
       for _ in self.file:          # < try to read again does nothing
           self.lines += 1          # < this never runs

    def replace(self, old, new):
        replace = ''
        for line in self.file:      # < try to read again; loop again doesn't run
            replace += line.replace(old, new) + '\n'
        self.file.write(replace)
```

If you want to count lines and later read those lines one by one, just read the file into a list. Then `count` will be the length of the list. Something like:

```
class TextReader:
    def __init__(self, spec):
        self.file = open(spec, 'r+')
        # alternative to below:
        # self.lines = list(self.file)
        self.lines = []
        for line in self.file:
            self.lines.append(line)

    def replace(self, old, new):
        replace = ''
        for line in self.lines:
            replace += line.replace(old, new) + '\n'
        self.file.write(replace)
        self.file.close()       # remember to close the file!

t = TextReader('test.txt')
t.replace('good', 'bad')
print(t.lines)
print(len(t.lines))
```

This will result in a file with two lines -- your original line and the appended line with `good` replaced with `bad`. This is because your are opening with `r+` which means append.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explain why your code isn't working. So it's correct that you'll need to close your file after your done otherwise that can cause memory leaks. Also I recommend using `with` since it automatically opens and closes you file for you. This is how I would do it.

```
class TextReader:
   def __init__(self, spec):
      self.file = spec
      self.text = ''
      self.lines = 0
      with open(spec, 'r') as f:
         for line in f:
            self.text += line
            self.lines += 1

   def replace(self, old, new):
      with open(self.file, "w") as f:
         r = ''
         for line in self.text.split("\n"):
            r += line.replace(old, new) + '\n'
         f.write(r)

t = TextReader('temp.txt')
t.replace('good', 'bad')
print(t.text)
print(t.lines)
```

It automatically close your file for you and reopen to write over the current text replacing the words you want, since 'r+' will append to the end of the file.